# How to create Javafx TableView based on excel file

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

So I wanna build TableView from excel file.

This Excel file doesn't have defined number of columns, so if I load first excel file it can have 5 columns, second one could have 7, etc ...

My problem is that I don't know how to make this "dynamic" number of columns in TableView.

```
 TableColumn [] tc = new TableColumn[r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()];
    for(int i=0;i< r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++){
        tc[i] = new TableColumn(r.getCell(i).toString());
        tc[i].setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<String,String>(??????)
            );
        excelTable.getColumns().add(tc[i]);
    }
```

So this following creates columns and sets their name. But now I wanna load data rows from excel to table. The troubling part is where "??????" are. Since I don't know what names of my columns will be I can't make class with attributes.

Whole code:

public class ExcelController {

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelMethods.class);
private ExcelMethods ex;


@FXML
TableView excelTable;

@FXML
Pane rootPane;

public void initialize() {
    logger.info("Excel controller initalized");
    ex = new ExcelMethods();
}

/**
 * select and load excel file into program
 * loading excel file into system is
 * happening here
 */
public void loadExcelSheet() {
    logger.info("loadExcelSheet function selected");
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Excel File");
    File excel = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(rootPane.getScene().getWindow());
    if (excel != null) {
        logger.info("File loaded successfully");
        Path path = Paths.get(excel.getPath());
        ex.loadWorkbook(path);

        loadTableData();
    } else
        logger.info("User did not select any file to load");
}

public void saveExcelSheet() {
    logger.info("saveExcelSheet function selected");
    DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    dirChooser.setTitle("Save Excel File");
    File excel = dirChooser.showDialog(rootPane.getScene().getWindow());
    if (excel != null) {
        logger.info("File selected successfully");
        Path path = Paths.get(excel.getPath());
        ex.saveExcel(ex.wb, path);
    } else
        logger.info("User did not select any file to save into");
}

/**
 * loads table from loaded excel file
 */
public void loadTableData() {

    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> excelData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    logger.info("Populating table ...");
    excelTable.setEditable(true);
    excelTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    Sheet sh = ex.selectSheet(ex.wb);
    Row r = ex.getRow(sh, 0);

    //laod columsn into List
    for(int i=0;i<r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++){
        columns.add(r.getCell(i).toString());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++){
        final int finalIdx = i;
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columns.get(i));
        column.setCellValueFactory(
                param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().get(finalIdx)));
        excelTable.getColumns().add(column);

    }

    r = ex.getRow(sh, 1);
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        row.add(r.getCell(i).toString());
        excelData.add(row);
    }
    excelTable.setItems(excelData);


    }



}
```

Comment: You can't use a `PropertyValueFactory` in this case. Just implement the cell value factory yourself.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could provide small example , if it is not too much of a bother ? Thanks

Comment: With looking into duplicate and modifying my code I get : Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1, I updated above question to show whole code. Only columns are shown and no data is set in rows.